# understand GDB output for new thread (Linux systag)

Tags: linux, gdb, pthreads

I am currently debugging an application which uses pthreads. When I attach GDB
it continuously prints messages of this form:

[New Thread **a_hex_number** (LWP **a_dec_number**)]

I assume that **a_hex_number** is an address, but whose address it is?
I assume **a_dec_number** is a unique identifier for created thread, is it?

Are my assumptions right? 
Can anyone give me more detail about the numbers and their meaning?
I already read [this document](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) but I am still having trouble to get the full picture.
Probably an info about the Linux systags would help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that a_hex_number is an address, but whose address it is?

It's the address of a thread descriptor (on Linux also the result of `pthread_self()` call).

> I assume a_dec_number is a unique identifier for created thread, is it?

No, it's the thread-id assigned by the kernel to this thread. It's the same thing as visible in `ps` output (on Linux, `clone(2)` threads and processes have very few differences at the kernel level).